# Send large string as mail file attachment

Tags: php, email, compression

I have a need to send a very large string (say 25MB) as an `mail()` attachment.  I don't want to create a file on the server and attach that file. The large string needs to be compressed (using gzip?) then attached to the mail.

I can attach a text string to a mail message as attachment. But since the string is so large, the string needs to be compressed so that the host server can mail it, and then the mail recipient needs to be able to save the attachment locally and uncompress.

Assume that there are no memory limitations to the process. Also assume that the process must use the PHP `mail()` function, and not any mail add-ins (like PHPMailer). (The process is a WordPress plugin, so it can't assume the existence of an add-in like PHPMailer.) Also assume at least PHP 5.6.

How do I compress a string 'on the fly' and attach that compressed string to an email that can be uncompressed by the recipient?

Thanks.

Comment: just curious . why is it just a string not a file ? attachment will be a file at the end . is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/423316/zod   As a WordPress plugin, it will be running on other site's servers, not a server of my own control. I don't want to write files to another's server. It is not necessary for there to be a file to attach content to an email as an attachment.